# PHP 7.1 Class not found in a Discord lib

Tags: php, class, discord

I use this Discord lib https://github.com/teamreflex/oauth2-discord

And I get this error:

> [error] 8370#8370: *321961 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP
>   Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Discord\OAuth\Parts\Guild' not
>   found in
>   /home/razvan/discord/vendor/team-reflex/oauth2-discord/src/Discord/Discord.php:172
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 /home/razvan/discord/vendor/team-reflex/oauth2-discord/src/Discord/Parts/User.php(62):
>   Discord\OAuth\Discord->buildPart('Discord\OAuth\P...',
>   Object(League\OAuth2\Client\Token\AccessToken), Array)
>   #1 /home/razvan/discord/vendor/team-reflex/oauth2-discord/src/Discord/Part.php(85):
>   Discord\OAuth\Parts\User->getGuildsAttribute()
>   #2 /home/razvan/discord/login.php(38): Discord\OAuth\Part->__get('guilds')
>   #3 {main}   thrown in /home/razvan/discord/vendor/team-reflex/oauth2-discord/src/Discord/Discord.php
>   on line 172" while reading response header from upstream, client:
>   82.76.7.106, server: discord.re, request: "GET /login.php?state=BDzUvmxBmT15Q1jDngE9fbSuysnd9qPm&code=mKn2TujOmBzdarKi9kDGcVpC4z0xGC
>   HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "discord.re"

This is my **login.php** page:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();


require_once __DIR__ . '/assets/discord_config.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/assets/db_config.php';

$provider = new \Discord\OAuth\Discord($discord_config);

if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
    header('Location: '. $provider->getAuthorizationUrl());
} else {
    $token = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
        'code' => $_GET['code'],
    ]);

// Get the user object.
$user = $provider->getResourceOwner($token);

// Get the guilds and connections.
$guilds = $user->guilds;

foreach ($guilds as $server) {
    if($server->owner) {
        $_SESSION['discord']['servers'][$server->id] = array(
            'id' => $server->id,
            'name' => $server->name,
            'icon' => $server->icon
        );
    }
}

//Add user to DB or get user ID from db
$mysql = new mysqlHelper($conn);
$mysql->add_user($user->username, $user->email, $user->discriminator);
$_SESSION['discord']['user']['id'] = $mysql->get_user_id($user->email);
$_SESSION['discord']['user']['name'] = $user->username;
$_SESSION['discord']['user']['email'] = $user->email;
$_SESSION['discord']['user']['discriminator'] = $user->discriminator;

//Redirect to main page
header('Location: index.php');
exit();

}
```